# BIML: automatic creation of OleDbDestinations for XMLSource in Dataflow

Tags: ssis, biml

I'm having a XML file with 2 outputpaths and 2 tables in my staging DB. Tables and outputpaths do have same names. 
Instead of writing 2 times OleDbDestination and changing Inputpath and ExternalTableOutput I would like to use some Bimlscript.

My current solution:

```
<Dataflow Name="DF_MyXml">
    <Transformations>
        <XmlSource Name="MyXml">
            <FileInput ConnectionName="simple.xml" />
            <XmlSchemaFileInput ConnectionName="simple.xsd" />
        </XmlSource>
        <OleDbDestination Name="Database" ConnectionName="Dest">
            <InputPath OutputPathName =  "MyXml.Database" />
            <ExternalTableOutput Table="Database" />
        </OleDbDestination>
        <OleDbDestination Name="Project" ConnectionName="Dest">
            <InputPath OutputPathName =  "MyXml.Project" />
            <ExternalTableOutput Table="Project" />
        </OleDbDestination>
    </Transformations>
</Dataflow>
```

What I would like to achive:

```
<Dataflow Name="DF_MyXML">
    <Transformations>
        <XmlSource Name="MyXml">
            <FileInput ConnectionName="simple.xml" />
            <XmlSchemaFileInput ConnectionName="simple.xsd" />
        </XmlSource>
        <#foreach (var OutP in ["myXML"].DataflowOutputs) { #>
            <OleDbDestination Name="<#=OutP.Name#>" ConnectionName="Dest">
                <InputPath OutputPathName =  "MyXml.<#=OutP.Name#>" />
                <ExternalTableOutput Table="<#=OutP.Name#>" />
            </OleDbDestination>
        <# } #>
    </Transformations>
</Dataflow>
```

Sadly this isn't working. ;-)

In  [API-Documentation for AstXMLSourceNode](https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Api/Type/AstXmlSourceNode) I found the property "DataflowOutputs" which "Gets a collection of all dataflow output paths for this transformation" (sounds promising, uhh?) but I can't even figure out how to reference the XMLSource in Bimlscript in any way.

Starting from RootNode I was able to find my Dataflow-Task but then I got stuck and didn't manage to "find" my Transformations\XMLSource.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

BTW: if there is a solution to automatically create destination-tables based on a given XSD this would be greate too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your connections are declared in a separate file to be easily accessed in Biml script. You can mess with Console.WriteLine() to print out details about objects to the output window and get a glimpse of what is going on in the BimlScript.

In the second file, traditionally called Environmnet.biml,

you need (only with your xml file connection info, the data here is just a placeholder):

```
<Connections>
        <FileConnection Name="XmlFile" FilePath="C:\test\XmlFile.xml" RelativePath="true" />
        <FileConnection Name="XmlXsd" FilePath="C:\test\XmlXsd.Xsd" RelativePath="true" />
</Connections>
```

then you can do something to the effect of :

```
var fileConnection = RootNode.Connections["XmlFile"];
```

(sorry before I accidentally put DbConnections)

and play with it from there. I do not have any xml files at my disposal right now to play around with to help you get the exact information that you are looking for. I will update on Monday.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work (at least in my example). On importDB() I get an error message "object reference not set to object instance"; I think thats because simple.xsd isn't of type dbconnections.